# How to extract x and y values from ezplot function that plots a probability density function of a gaussian mixture model

Tags: matlab, gaussian

I'm fitting a Gaussian mixture model of 2 clusters over a group of variables (mydata). I can easily use ezplot and PDF to plot the GMM function. Please help to extract the x and y values of this plot.

```
myGMM=gmdistribution.fit(mydata,2);
ezplot(@(x)pdf(myGMM,x),[0 2000]);
```

I would really appreciate that.
thanks so much,
Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you specify an output argument for `ezplot`, it will return a handle to the plot objects. You can then access the `XData` and `YData` properties of this handle to get the x and y coordinates of the result

```
h = ezplot('x^2');
x = get(h, 'XData');
y = get(h, 'YData');
```

Comment: Thanks so much. That really helped me!